# Python error when batching a Graphical Modeler script [QGIS 3.4.9]

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, batch, qgis-modeler

I have a very simple Model to convert a table in points and to extract some features by their attributes. I can run it without any problem, except if I do it as a batching process.

I received this error:

[image]

This error occurs since I upgraded my QGIS version to the last LTR.

EDIT: I've tried to change the lines in the wrappers.py file as proposed by etrimaille and I cannot find the lines in my wrappers.py file
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in QGIS itself.
It has been reported and already fixed. You need to wait for QGIS 3.4.10 on July 19th or you can manually apply this fix in your QGIS installation: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/30443/files

Bug report: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30410

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find the lines to correct in my QGIS wrappers.py file (placed in C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\processing\gui).